# create dynamic image corresponding to available data on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

My home page is displaying images slideshow using jquery,all these images are retrieving from mysql during the run time.I have created 9 images inside the division which are moving by jquery and  i am giving the value of image url from codebehind.please see my code below,if database contains lesser than 9 images,null image should be hidden.how can i do it?

```
 <a href="#">
```

```
  DataTable dt = Db.ids("home_table");
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Handler1.ashx?id=" + Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[0]["id"].ToString());


Image2.ImageUrl = "~/Handler1.ashx?id=" + Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[1]["id"].ToString());
```

This method is followed for all 9 images...

Comment: Just a comment. I don't see why you are converting a string to an `Int16` and then back to a string. Just concatenate the database `ToString()` value straight on to the URL part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error because you directly access rows that do not exist. You need to count the numbers of rows in your DT.

```
numberOfRows = dt.Rows.Count
```

And after that

```
if ( numberOfRows >= 2 )
{
   Image2.ImageUrl = "~/Handler1.ashx?id=" + ...    }

if ( numberOfRows >= 3 )
{
   Image3.ImageUrl = "~/Handler1.ashx?id=" + ....    }
```

etc.

Comment: yea..but now i want to add 50 images,some time database may contain less than 50 images,so what to do?

Comment: That's a different question. So your real question is that you want a flexible number of images in your DIV? In that case you cannot hardcode them in the page like you have done now with image1, image2 etc. You should use a repeater or dynamically add image controls to the page

Comment: yea..i added dynamic images,but,jquery is not moving the images if create image dynamically.All images should be inside a div,that div should not be used runat="server"

Answer (score 2):

You can't concatenate a string and an integer:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Handler1.ashx?id=" + Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[0]["id"]);
```

Convert `ToString()` to resolve:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Handler1.ashx?id=" + Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[0]["id"]).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve.

Easy way:

You can create a static array of your Image controls (an array with 9 elements) then in a loop from zero to number of images-1.   You then de-reference into that array to change the url.  Should look like this (example code, non-compiled, might have bugs or typos)

Decl:

```
Image imageArray[] = { Image1, Image2 ... , Image9};
```

In the loop:

```
imageArray[index].ImageUrl = "~/Handler1.ashx?id=" + Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[index]["id"].ToString());
```

Or the hard way:

Dynamically add image controls to the page.

Comment: i have already tried this,but jquery is not moving the images when i add images codebehind,i must be able to add images inside the div without using "runtime=server" tag,then only jquery can move these images